# UIView cannot be unhidden

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `UILabel` in a `UIView` which are all hidden by default:

[image: UIView]

All 3 elements should be unhidden after the Login button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func signinTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    loading.hidden = false
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
```

All 3 elements should be hidden again after it has received a response from the server:

```
                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                        prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                        prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                        prefs.synchronize()

                        loading.hidden = true
                        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_attendance", sender: self)
                    }
```

However, the elements are **not unhidden** after Login button is tapped.

I have tried to test it by creating a button just to hide and unhide the elements, and it works. Thus, all the outlets and variable names are correct.

It just wouldn't hide and unhide when there are other functions before it such as setting the `prefs:NSUserDefaults` as shown in my above code.

Comment: If you are doing that in the background thread, you should do the UI changes in the main thread.

Comment: Could you show use the full method? Which including the   if(success == 1) { NSLog("Login SUCCESS"); block?

Comment: @JasonNam Sure, will update post in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    loading.hidden = true
    activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
})
```